# SQL Transaction Duplicate Entry

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is the first time i've used IF Exists and BEGIN TRANSACTION. I get an error on 'incorrect syntax near ')' in the If Exists part and incorrect syntax near 'Transaction' at the end of End Transaction. What I'm trying todo is raise an error if a duplicate Entry exists and if there is an error rollback the transaction and return the error or return @@RowCount i don't know which one I should choose could someone correct my procedure and make any adjustments on it please.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Forums WHERE Title = @Title) 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Duplicate Entry', 16, 1)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO Forums(AddedBy, AddedDate, Title, Description, 
               ParentID, Moderated, ImageUrl, UpdatedBy, UpdatedDate, Active, Importance)
        VALUES(@AddedBy, @AddedDate, @Title, null, null, False, null, null, null, True, 0)
        RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
    END


IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RETURN @@ERROR
    END

END TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Two quick comments: (1) `END TRANSACTION` is not valid. (2) You should send `@@ROWCOUNT` back to the client using output parameters, not `RETURN`. `RETURN` is for error codes, not data. If you just want to return that the insert succeeded, return 1 or some special number to indicate success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a transaction unless you wanna enforce an isolation level, or if you have more than one Update/Insert/Delete statement, and you need to roll them all back if an error happens, or commit them all if everything is successful,

in your sample code, you have an insert statement that won't even get to execute, so you have nothing to rollback

```
DECLARE @InsertedRows INT = 0

INSERT INTO Forums(AddedBy, AddedDate, Title, Description, ParentID, 
    Moderated, ImageUrl, UpdatedBy, UpdatedDate, Active, Importance)
SELECT @AddedBy, @AddedDate, @Title, null, null, 'False', null, null, null, 'True', 0
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Forums WHER Title = @Title)


SET @InsertedRows = @@ROWCOUNT

IF @InsertedRows = 1 
  RETURN 1
ELSE
  RETURN -1
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Why an I getting invalid column for False and True

Comment: @KDM not sure I know what you mean by getting invalid columns for False and True

Comment: I just put quotes around them and it worked sweet as thanks for you're answer though. but what if I did get an error during an insert statement what then could you provide an update to you're answer

Comment: @KDM now I see what you mean, fixed!!

Comment: What if you get an error in an insert statement and is it likely if so how would you write error hangling for that? update you're code

Comment: You're missing a `SET` on the line where you assign `ROWCOUNT`. You also haven't incorporated any error handling which @KDM subsequently asked about.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Forums WHERE Title = @Title) 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Duplicate Entry', 16, 1)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN   
          INSERT INTO Forums(AddedBy, AddedDate, Title, Description, ParentID, 
              Moderated, ImageUrl, UpdatedBy, UpdatedDate, Active, Importance)
          VALUES(@AddedBy, @AddedDate, @Title, null, null, False, null, null, null, True, 0)

          COMMIT TRANSACTION

        RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
    END

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RETURN @@ERROR
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the transaction. A single-row insert is either going to succeed or fail (and `@@ROWCOUNT` is only every going to return 1 in this case). And if you have a unique constraint on the title column (which you should have, apparently), you don't need to check first, either, though it may be a bit more efficient to do so (I'll have to perform some tests to confirm, but I'm pretty sure the error mechanism is pretty costly). Anyway here is a version with error handling in case something should go wrong other than a constraint violation on the title:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Forums WHERE Title = @Title)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Duplicate entry', 16, 1);
    RETURN 2627; -- key constraint violation
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT dbo.Forums
        (
          AddedBy, AddedDate, Title, 
          Description, ParentID, 
          Moderated, ImageUrl, UpdatedBy, 
          UpdatedDate, Active, Importance
        )
        SELECT
          @AddedBy,
          @AddedDate,
          @Title, 
          NULL, NULL, 
          'False', -- did you mean 0?
          NULL, NULL, NULL,
          'True', -- did you mean 1?
          0;

        RETURN 1;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(4000) = 'Insert failed ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
        RAISERROR(@msg, 16, 1);
        RETURN ERROR_NUMBER();
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: I simply suggested a different solution that doesn't require all this error handling logic on the database side but rather handle it in the domain logic. This situation is simple enough, you either manage to insert or you don't.

Comment: is it possible that you end up in the ELSE block and in the mean time someone else insert a record with the same title? what happens now? maybe you need to use an isolation level to protect against that. OH sweet complexity!!!!

Comment: That's the point of the additional `TRY`/`CATCH` logic. If someone else beat you to it with the same title, only one of you will win. I don't think a less concurrent isolation level solves the problem - you still have two users trying to insert the same title, and only one can do it.

Comment: For your solution to work he must have a unique constraint on Title, which does not seem to be the case, and if has a unique constraint then the whole if else is useless really, all he has to do is catch the exception that SQL Server will through

Comment: Like I said in my answer, **if you have a unique constraint on the title column** - also I am fairly confident that trapping the error yourself will be more efficient than just throwing it over the wall at `TRY`/`CATCH`... if you can predict failure conditions without invoking expensive error handling, why not do so? Anyway, you got your answer accepted and you're the only one who has received any votes (even though you still haven't addressed error handling), so why are you complaining about my answer?